# ¿Cómo asignar un nuevo valor en una colección de un data set?

Tags: sql-server, visual-basic

Tengo la duda de como puedo asignarle un nuevo valor a un dataset que obtengo de un procedimiento almacenado de SQL server, ya que necesito cambiar el valor de saldo para poder mostrarlo en una consulta de un formulario

El código que estoy usando es este para obtener el dataset

```
    If ChkEstiloColor.Checked = False Then
        VlDatos = CLLibreria.MdlFunciones.Procesos.BuscaKardexProductoNew(CbbTiendas.SelectedValue.ToString, CbbBodega.SelectedValue.ToString, TxtProducto.Tag.ToString, CmbDesde.SelectedValue.ToString, Vstatus)
    Else
        VlDatos = CLLibreria.MdlFunciones.Procesos.BuscaKardexEstiloColorNew(CbbTiendas.SelectedValue.ToString, CbbBodega.SelectedValue.ToString, TxtDescripcion.Tag.ToString, CmbDesde.SelectedValue, Vstatus)
    End If
```

y para poder ir cambiando los valores del saldo de cada linea estaba probando con este pero no me cambia el valor

```
    If TxtProducto.Text = "APORTE-MKTG-MISC" Then
        If VlDatos.Tables.Count > 0 Then
            For Each saldo As DataSet In VlDatos.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Saldo")
                saldo.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Saldo") = 0

            Next
        Else
            VlDatos.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Saldo") = 0
        End If

    End If
```

El resultado del dataset es el que se muestra en la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te faltaría declarar saldo como una variable del tipo DataRow.

```
        For Each saldo As DataRow In VlDatos.Tables(0).Rows

             saldo.Item("Saldo") = 0

        Next
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yo creo que tener un bot que vaya dicíendo este tipo de mensajes ocupa más que ayuda. si mi respuesta es insuficiente para resolver el problema es la propia comunidad la que lo puede hacer saber.